# How disk space is partitioned in an Android phone?

Tags: storage, partitions

How does storage space in our phone is partitioned? How can we access our storage space?

Comment: You can see partitions and their usage in apps like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Android phones have `eMMC` (flash memory), partitioned in GUID partition table (`GPT`) just like a PC's hard disk. There are usually less or more 50 partitions on a latest Android phone. OS uses `/system` while user uses `/data` mainly. Internal SD card is `/data/media`. Other partitions are smaller.

For more details, visit this [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565).

If you have a rooted phone, you can use Linux tools (`parted`, `gdisk` etc.) to manipulate Android 's partition table. But that's really risky.

To fully access storage space, you need root permissions.

**RELATED:** [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)