# How to take full image backup of partitions or eMMC?

Tags: adb, backup, twrp, fastboot, partitions

I have an Archos 55 Platinum here. There is also a unofficial TWRP, if this might help.
I would like to make a backup of the storage of the phone, like `dd` for any partition, so I can inspect the content later.

Also, I don't want to root or flash anything, nor install apps.

Is there a way that allows me to run TWRP via fastboot instead of flashing? Any ideas how I can proceed?

Comment: @IrfanLatif isn't that an answer? Note that at least when on Linux, you can also use `adb exec-out dd if=/dev/block/(bootdevice/)mmcblk0 > mmcblk0.img` to store the images directly on your computer instead of on the Android device. TWRP has ADB enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can boot in TWRP if bootloader is unlocked:

```
fastboot boot /path/to/twrp.img
```

Then you can simply `dd` whole eMMC or individual partitions. You need some  extra memory (on external SD card) to backup whole eMMC or `/data` partition. Smaller partitions (including the biggest one: `system`) can be backed up to internal memory i.e. data partition.

**For Qualcomm SoC:**
(for MTK devices, path is slightly different)

```
dd if=/dev/block/(bootdevice/)mmcblk0 of=/path/to/external-sd/emmc-backup
```

For single partition:

```
dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata of=/path/to/external-sd/data-backup
```

In order to come up with shortage of space, instead of using SD Card you may save backup files directly to PC using `adb shell` or `exec-out`. Thanks to @Izzy:

```
adb exec-out dd if=/dev/block/(bootdevice/)mmcblk0 > emmc-backup.img
```

Make sure your `adb` binary (on Windows or Linux) supports [exec-out](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/adb/commandline.cpp#1553). Also take care that unwanted non-printing terminal characters don't get included in output.

There are also other methods like `adb pull`, UMS or streaming over network. For details see [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)

**PS:**

Another way to save space and to speed up backup process is to backup only the contents of mountable filesystems instead of whole partition image. Particularly `userdata` and `system` are larger partitions but they aren't usually completely filled. Mount them and create backup archive using `tar` so that zeroed out portion of these partitions isn't backed up.

Make sure to preserve all file permissions and attributes (whatever applicable depending on filesystem etc.) including classic UNIX file mode and owner, ACLs, XATTRs and SELinux contexts.   These options are supported by `tar`. Otherwise things might get messed up. See more details in [How to stream an encrypted backup of the entire device to remote host?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219261/218526)

---

**RELATED:**

- [How disk space is partitioned in an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201224/218526)
- [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)
- [Is there any way to recover data from 2nd SD partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190852/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question I did use the method described above:

```
~$ adb exec-out dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata > data.img
```

But there is an issue, the image will be encrypted if the data is not decrypted first. File and folder names will be gibberish.

The only way I got decrypted data was via TWRP, because it asks for decryption password on start.

And then I was able to copy the data via mtp.

I know this may not seem on topic on how to recover files, but this question is getting a lot of traffic and the proposed solution has a drawback and I'm not allowed to comment right now.