# How to stream an encrypted backup of the entire device to remote host?

Tags: root-access, backup, insufficient-memory, command-line, ssh

I have an Android device that has no free space and no SD-card that I can replace (thanks to OnePlus policy). I also have no free space on PC to accommodate the backup so I wanted to upload it to the cloud. I have SSH and root access to the device. I also have a remote FTP server space (that I not trust, though).

I would like to make a password protected `tar` or `zip` file and upload it there. I'm not sure if a zip of `/` is sufficient for backup purposes.

The problem is there is no free space left on the device so I need to create the `zip` file on the fly and "stream" it to the backup server (it's SFTP on port 30).

I checked that the SSH, `rsync` and `zip` commands are available but I'm not sure how to do a full backup, encrypted `zip` compression and SFTP upload without writing to the disk.

How can I combine commands to do that while connected to the device over SSH?

Comment: I feel this lack of space everywhere may be a common situation...

Comment: usually backup of /data is enough, but make sure to preserve selinux context too (besides uid/gid and permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have **authenticated** login, **encrypted** archive, **rsync** and multiple transport **protocols** (including HTTP, WebDAV, FTP and SSH/SFTP) in one tool: [`rclone`](https://rclone.org). It supports **local filesystem** and a number of **cloud storage**. Additionally it does have all of the four mentioned **servers builtin**. It means that all you need on both sides is `rclone`. **No root access** is necessary either. If you want to **mount remote directory** (using `rclone mount`), however, that requires FUSE support and root access on Android.

`rclone` does have builtin encryption i.e. files on remote will be created encrypted. Also there are multiple authentication methods supported including username/password and RSA keys (with SFTP), but those are usually unnecessary when encryption is already there.

A simple use case:

**On server:**

Run minimal SSH server if not already running:

```
~$ mkdir -p BackupDir/Encrypted
~$ rclone serve sftp --user <username> --pass <password> --addr :2222 BackupDir
```

**On phone:**

Create obscure password:

```
~$ rclone obscure <password>
```

Create configuration file (use `rclone config` for simple steps):

```
# rclone.conf

[PLAIN_TARGET]
type = sftp
host = <server_ip>
port = 2222
user = <username>
pass = <obscure_password>
#key_file = /path/to/.ssh/id_rsa

[CRYPT_TARGET]
type = crypt
remote = PLAIN_TARGET:/Encrypted
filename_encryption = standard
directory_name_encryption = true
password = <obscure_password>
```

Copy test file to server without and with encryption:

```
~$ echo Hi >test_file
~$ rclone --config rclone.conf sync test_file PLAIN_TARGET:/
~$ rclone --config rclone.conf sync test_file CRYPT_TARGET:/
```

SFTP supports modification **timestamps**, WebDAV and FTP both don't. However **symlinks** cannot be transferred as symlinks, those are either ignored or original file is copied or `.rclonelink` file is created. A way to copy symlinks and all metadata including timestamps, **extended attributes** (like SELinux labels), and **ACLs** is to throw `tar` stream at `rclone rcat`:

```
~$ tar --xattrs -cpvzf - test_file | rclone rcat CRYPT_TARGET:/test_file.tgz
```

Similarly you can get back the file using `rclone cat`. This will also largely reduce **transfer time** (even up to less than half) particularly if you have large number of small-sized files. Adding reasonable **compression** to `tar` may even reduce space usage and time, but high compression can go wrong too. However this way **incremental sync won't work** and you need to `untar` to use files on remote. It's also possible (by some scripting) to find only changed files first by running `rclone check` or by passing option `--dry-run` to `rclone sync` command and then add those files to `tar` archive.

> I'm not sure if a zip of `/` is sufficient for backup purposes.

On Android rootfs `/` contains a number of directories and mount points - pseudo filesystems like `sysfs`, `procfs` and read-only filesystems like `system` and `vendor` partitions - which cannot be or don't need to be backed up. User settings, apps data and personal data is stored in `/data` partition. For details see [Android Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565) and [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526).

So you can backup selected directories from `/data` or the whole partition at maximum. However, as mentioned by @[alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470) in comment, if you intend to restore apps data (in `/data/data`), you'll have to minutely take care of files metadata - in particular UIDs/GIDs and SELinux contexts.

Say you want to backup whole `/data` partition, do:

```
~# tar --xattrs -cpvzf - /data | rclone -P rcat PLAIN_TARGET:/data.tgz
```

For ideas on how to dump complete partitions (block devices), see [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know the program. I wanted to do a backup in such a way that I could restore both rom, apps and internal memory card.

Comment: ROM is on `/system`, `/vendor` and `boot` partitions, apps and internal SD card are on `/data`. You can backup all of those using `rclone` without any constraint.

Comment: busybox tar does not support `--xattrs` tar binary from https://opengapps.org is required. only `--selinux` flag will handle `RHT.security.` so better use both flags (for higher compatibility) at least on gnu tar selinux flag is mandatory for proper restoring

Comment: @alecxs right..