# "Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation"...when trying to backup through abd (TWRP)

Tags: root-access, backup, recovery-mode, twrp, usb-debugging

Phone: Moto C Plus

Phone OS: Android 7.0

PC OS: Windows 7

TWRP: 3.1.1

Rooted

I'm trying to backup directly to PC from TWRP recovery through adb cmd.

The cmd `adb devices` shows the device id and the word "recovery" next to it, meaning i'm connected successfully and that i'm in recovery. USB debugging is on.

But `adb backup --twrp` shows...

**WARNING: adb backup is deprecated and may be removed in a future release**

**Now Unlock your device and confirm backup operation**

followed by the current directory.

But nothing happens on the phone. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clBVD6QOpRQ) is what's supposed to happen. Skip to 3:26.

Any insight?

Comment: Ifyou have no space left the only option would be to create the backup on-device and stream the backup file data directly to the PC using `adb exec-out ...`. See for example [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203891/how-to-take-full-image-backup-of-partitions-or-emmc/203913#203913) which performs a low-level backup. Not sure if twrp backup support this on a higher level.

Comment: @Robert Can you help me breakdown this cmd 'adb exec-out dd if=/dev/block/(bootdevice/)mmcblk0 > emmc-backup.img' What changes would i have to make to suite my particular need?

Comment: *'adb pull /dev/block/dm-0 data.img'* or if not encrypted *'adb pull /dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.msdc0/by-name/userdata data.img'*

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your backup. You are just impatient. Please ignore *WARNING adb backup is deprecated... Now Unlock your device and confirm...* that is just because the adb.exe doesn't know what's going on at phone side.

You should see TWRP backup starting at phone display immediately without any confirmation

watch the `backup.ab` growing until backup process is complete

i recommend to backup each partition for it's own, that way you avoid trouble with some old bug TWRP just restoring first partition

```
adb backup "-f twrp_data.ab --twrp --compress data"
```

you can convert that `backup.ab` later into `data.ext4.win` with [twab.sh](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81905363&postcount=7) (linux only)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111562/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-now-unlock-your-device-and-confirm-the-backup-op).

Comment: fyi: reason for *adb backup --twrp* not working is *adbd* isn't running with root privileges in this TWRP built (claim it to TWRP maintainer)