# Retrieving messages from phone where cannot see screen

Tags: sms, data-recovery, screen, lineageos, usb-on-the-go

I damaged my old phone. The screen is almost completely shattered to the point I cannot see or touch it. Everything else works fine. I have a USB otg cable and can use a keyboard to type in my PIN. Is there a way I can retrieve my text messages? Even if I could just mount it for file transfer so I can copy over the latest backups that would be great. Now if I plug it into a computer nothing shows up because it's in 'charging only' mode. It is running LineageOS with root enabled. I thought it had adb but it is not working. I also can get into TWRP but can't get by the lock screen, I seem to recall the OTG doesn't work with TWRP.

Contents of `recovery.log` from `adb pull`

```
Starting TWRP 3.5.2_9-0-2bc3eccd on Mon Nov 13 05:17:09 1972
 (pid 590)
BOARD_HAS_NO_REAL_SDCARD := true
RECOVERY_SDCARD_ON_DATA := true
I:Lun file '/sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/file' does not exist, USB storage mode disabled
TW_INCLUDE_CRYPTO := true
I:TW_BRIGHTNESS_PATH := /sys/class/leds/wled/brightness
I:Found brightness file at '/sys/class/leds/wled/brightness'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 1600
I:LANG: en
Starting the UI...
setting DRM_FORMAT_RGB565 and GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565
cannot find/open a drm device: No such file or directory
fb0 reports (possibly inaccurate):
  vi.bits_per_pixel = 32
  vi.red.offset   =   0   .length =   8
  vi.green.offset =   8   .length =   8
  vi.blue.offset  =  16   .length =   8
setting GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
double buffered
framebuffer: 0 (720 x 1280)
Using fbdev graphics.
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 1600
I:Loading package: splash (/twres/splash.xml)
I:Load XML directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/splash.xml' directly
I:Checking resolution...
I:Scaling theme width 0.666667x and height 0.666667x, offsets x: 0 y: 0 w: 0 h: 0
I:Loading resources...
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Loading page splash
I:Switching packages (splash)
=> Linking mtab
=> Processing /etc/recovery.fstab for SAR-detection
I:Reading /etc/recovery.fstab
I:Done processing fstab files
I:SAR-DETECT: SAR System detected
=> Processing /etc/recovery.fstab
I:Reading /etc/recovery.fstab
I:Processing '/boot'
I:Processing '/system'
I:Created '/system_root' folder.
I:Processing '/system_image'
I:Processing '/vendor'
I:Processing '/vendor_image'
I:Processing '/oem'
I:Processing '/cache'
I:Processing '/data'
I:FBE contents 'ice', filenames ''
I:Processing '/recovery'
I:Processing '/dsp'
I:Created '/dsp' folder.
I:Processing '/misc'
I:Processing '/firmware'
I:Processing '/bt_firmware'
I:Created '/bt_firmware' folder.
I:Processing '/efs1'
I:Processing '/efs2'
I:Processing '/mnt/vendor/persist'
I:Created '/mnt/vendor/persist' folder.
I:Processing '/sdcard1'
I:Created '/sdcard1' folder.
I:Processing '/usb-otg'
I:Created '/usb-otg' folder.
I:Done processing fstab files
I:Setting up '/data' as data/media emulated storage.
I:mount -o bind '/data/media' '/sdcard' process ended with RC=0
I:mount -o bind '/data/media/0' '/sdcard' process ended with RC=0
I:File Based Encryption is present
e4crypt_initialize_global_de
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
calling retrieveAndInstallKey
Key exists, using: /data/unencrypted/key
Using Keymaster HAL: 3 from QTI for encryption.  Security level: TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT, HAL: android.hardware.keymaster@3.0::IKeymasterDevice/default
begin failed, code -62
Upgrading key in memory only: /data/unencrypted/key
Key upgraded in memory but not updated in folder: /data/unencrypted/key
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
Added key 212974880 (ext4:7e2c2ec01f8f350c) to keyring 41419702 in process 590
Added key 144230274 (f2fs:7e2c2ec01f8f350c) to keyring 41419702 in process 590
Added key 232568469 (fscrypt:7e2c2ec01f8f350c) to keyring 41419702 in process 590
contents mode 'ice' filenames 'aes-256-heh'
Wrote system DE key reference to:/data/unencrypted/ref
e4crypt_init_user0
Preparing: /data/misc/vold/user_keys
Preparing: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/ce
Preparing: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/de
Skipping non-de-key ..
Skipping non-de-key .
Using Keymaster HAL: 3 from QTI for encryption.  Security level: TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT, HAL: android.hardware.keymaster@3.0::IKeymasterDevice/default
begin failed, code -62
Upgrading key in memory only: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0
Key upgraded in memory but not updated in folder: /data/misc/vold/user_keys/de/0
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
Added key 963511470 (ext4:1f22a164457530fa) to keyring 41419702 in process 590
Added key 866500849 (f2fs:1f22a164457530fa) to keyring 41419702 in process 590
Added key 400409343 (fscrypt:1f22a164457530fa) to keyring 41419702 in process 590
Installed de key for user 0
Using synthetic password method
Handle is '0c2d2ce4f11d9576'
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/data/system/users/0.xml' directly
Using synthetic password method
Handle is '0c2d2ce4f11d9576'
I:User 0 is not decrypted.
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/BH9086U09E'
I:Settings storage is '/data/media/0'
Updating partition details...
I:Data backup size is 16518MB, free: 1410MB.
I:Unable to mount '/sdcard1'
I:Actual block device: '', current file system: 'auto'
I:Unable to mount '/usb-otg'
I:Actual block device: '', current file system: 'auto'
...done
I:Unmounting main partitions...


Partition Logs:
/boot | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot | Size: 64MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img SlotSelect 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot
   Display_Name: Boot
   Storage_Name: boot
   Backup_Path: /boot
   Backup_Name: boot
   Backup_Display_Name: Boot
   Storage_Path: /boot
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/system_root | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system | Size: 4921MB Used: 2569MB Free: 2352MB Backup Size: 2569MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent SlotSelect Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system
   Display_Name: System
   Storage_Name: System
   Backup_Path: /system_root
   Backup_Name: system
   Backup_Display_Name: System
   Storage_Path: /system_root
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/system_image | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system | Size: 5000MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img SlotSelect 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system
   Display_Name: System Image
   Storage_Name: system_image
   Backup_Path: /system_image
   Backup_Name: system_image
   Backup_Display_Name: System Image
   Storage_Path: /system_image
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/vendor | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/vendor | Size: 1511MB Used: 384MB Free: 1127MB Backup Size: 384MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent SlotSelect Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/vendor
   Display_Name: Vendor
   Storage_Name: Vendor
   Backup_Path: /vendor
   Backup_Name: vendor
   Backup_Display_Name: Vendor
   Storage_Path: /vendor
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/vendor_image | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/vendor | Size: 1536MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img SlotSelect 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/vendor
   Display_Name: Vendor Image
   Storage_Name: vendor_image
   Backup_Path: /vendor_image
   Backup_Name: vendor_image
   Backup_Display_Name: Vendor Image
   Storage_Path: /vendor_image
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/oem | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/oem | Size: 371MB Used: 70MB Free: 300MB Backup Size: 70MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/oem
   Display_Name: OEM
   Storage_Name: OEM
   Backup_Path: /oem
   Backup_Name: oem
   Backup_Display_Name: OEM
   Storage_Path: /oem
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/cache | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache | Size: 352MB Used: 0MB Free: 351MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_During_Factory_Reset Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache
   Display_Name: Cache
   Storage_Name: Cache
   Backup_Path: /cache
   Backup_Name: cache
   Backup_Display_Name: Cache
   Storage_Path: /cache
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/data | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata | Size: 22169MB Used: 16518MB Free: 1410MB Backup Size: 16518MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_During_Factory_Reset Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent Can_Be_Encrypted Is_Encrypted Has_Data_Media Can_Encrypt_Backup Use_Userdata_Encryption Is_Storage Is_Settings_Storage 
   Symlink_Path: /data/media/0
   Symlink_Mount_Point: /sdcard
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
   Display_Name: Data
   Storage_Name: Internal Storage
   Backup_Path: /data
   Backup_Name: data
   Backup_Display_Name: Data
   Storage_Path: /data/media/0
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65537

/recovery | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/FOTAKernel | Size: 64MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/FOTAKernel
   Display_Name: FOTAKernel
   Storage_Name: FOTAKernel
   Backup_Path: /recovery
   Backup_Name: recovery
   Backup_Display_Name: FOTAKernel
   Storage_Path: /recovery
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/dsp | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/dsp | Size: 11MB Used: 10MB Free: 1MB Backup Size: 10MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/dsp
   Display_Name: dsp
   Storage_Name: dsp
   Backup_Path: /dsp
   Backup_Name: dsp
   Backup_Display_Name: dsp
   Storage_Path: /dsp
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/misc | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc | Size: 1MB
   Flags: IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc
   Display_Name: misc
   Storage_Name: misc
   Backup_Path: /misc
   Backup_Name: misc
   Backup_Display_Name: misc
   Storage_Path: /misc
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/firmware | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem | Size: 109MB Used: 89MB Free: 20MB Backup Size: 89MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent Mount_To_Decrypt Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modem
   Display_Name: Firmware
   Storage_Name: Firmware
   Backup_Path: /firmware
   Backup_Name: firmware
   Backup_Display_Name: Firmware
   Storage_Path: /firmware
   Current_File_System: vfat
   Fstab_File_System: vfat
   Backup_Method: files
   Mount_Flags: 0, Mount_Options: context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0

/bt_firmware | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/bluetooth | Size: 63MB Used: 0MB Free: 63MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent Mount_To_Decrypt Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/bluetooth
   Display_Name: BT Firmware
   Storage_Name: BT Firmware
   Backup_Path: /bt_firmware
   Backup_Name: bt_firmware
   Backup_Display_Name: BT Firmware
   Storage_Path: /bt_firmware
   Current_File_System: vfat
   Fstab_File_System: vfat
   Backup_Method: files
   Mount_Flags: 0, Mount_Options: context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0

/efs1 | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modemst1 | Size: 2MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up Has_SubPartition IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modemst1
   Display_Name: EFS
   Storage_Name: EFS
   Backup_Path: /efs1
   Backup_Name: efs1
   Backup_Display_Name: EFS
   Storage_Path: /efs1
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/efs2 | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modemst2 | Size: 2MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up Is_SubPartition IsPresent 
   SubPartition_Of: /efs1
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modemst2
   Display_Name: efs2
   Storage_Name: efs2
   Backup_Path: /efs2
   Backup_Name: efs2
   Backup_Display_Name: efs2
   Storage_Path: /efs2
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/mnt/vendor/persist | /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist | Size: 27MB Used: 0MB Free: 26MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/persist
   Display_Name: mnt/vendor/persist
   Storage_Name: mnt/vendor/persist
   Backup_Path: /mnt/vendor/persist
   Backup_Name: mnt/vendor/persist
   Backup_Display_Name: mnt/vendor/persist
   Storage_Path: /mnt/vendor/persist
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/sdcard1 |  | Size: 0MB Used: 0MB Free: 0MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Wipe_Available_in_GUI Removable Is_Storage 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
   Alternate_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0
   Display_Name: Micro SDcard
   Storage_Name: Micro SDcard
   Backup_Path: /sdcard1
   Backup_Name: sdcard1
   Backup_Display_Name: Micro SDcard
   Storage_Path: /sdcard1
   Current_File_System: auto
   Fstab_File_System: auto
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65538

/usb-otg |  | Size: 0MB Used: 0MB Free: 0MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Wipe_Available_in_GUI Removable Is_Storage 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/sdg1
   Alternate_Block_Device: /dev/block/sdg
   Display_Name: USB OTG
   Storage_Name: USB OTG
   Backup_Path: /usb-otg
   Backup_Name: usb-otg
   Backup_Display_Name: USB OTG
   Storage_Path: /usb-otg
   Current_File_System: auto
   Fstab_File_System: auto
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65539

I:Loading package: TWRP (/twres/ui.xml)
I:Load XML directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/zh_TW.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/zh_CN.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/uk.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/tr.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sv.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sk.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/ru.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pt_PT.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pt_BR.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/nl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/ja.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/it.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/hu.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/fr.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/es.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/el.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/de.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/cz.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
parsing languageFile
parsing languageFile done
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/ui.xml' directly
I:Checking resolution...
I:Scaling theme width 0.666667x and height 0.666667x, offsets x: 0 y: 0 w: 0 h: 0
I:Loading resources...
I:Failed to load image from indeterminate013, error -1
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Including file: /twres/portrait.xml...
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/portrait.xml' directly
I:Loading resources...
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Loading page main
I:Loading page main2
I:Loading page install
I:Loading page flash_confirm
I:Loading page flash_zip
I:Loading page flash_done
I:Loading page flash_sleep_and_reboot
I:Loading page flashimage_confirm
I:Loading page clear_vars
I:Loading page reboot_system_routine
I:Loading page confirm_action
I:Loading page action_page
I:Loading page singleaction_page
I:Loading page action_complete
I:Loading page filecheck
I:Loading page rebootcheck
I:Loading page wipe
I:Loading page advancedwipe
I:Loading page formatdata
I:Loading page formatdata_confirm
I:Loading page checkpartitionlist
I:Loading page partitionoptions
I:Loading page refreshfilesystem
I:Loading page selectfilesystem
I:Loading page backup
I:Loading page multiuser_warning
I:Loading page backup_options
I:Loading page backupname1
I:Loading page backupname2
I:Loading page backupencryption
I:Loading page backupencryption2
I:Loading page checkbackuppassword
I:Loading page backup_run
I:Loading page restore
I:Unable to open '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/BH9086U09E'
I:Loading page restore_read
I:Loading page restore_decrypt
I:Loading page try_restore_decrypt
I:Loading page restore_select
I:Loading page renamebackup
I:Loading page restore_run
I:Loading page mount
I:Loading page usb_mount
I:Loading page usb_umount
I:Loading page system_readonly_check
I:Loading page reboot
I:Loading page reboot2
I:Loading page installapp
I:Loading page system_readonly
I:Loading page settings
I:Loading page settings_timezone
I:Loading page settings_screen
I:Loading page settings_vibration
I:Loading page settings_language
I:Loading page copylog
I:Loading page advanced
I:Loading page partsdcardsel
I:Loading page partsdcardcheck
I:Loading page partsdcard
I:Loading page htcdumlock
I:Loading page repackselect
I:Loading page repackconfirm
I:Loading page lock
I:Loading page filemanagerlist
I:Loading page filemanageroptions
I:Loading page choosedestinationfolder
I:Loading page filemanagerrenamefile
I:Loading page filemanagerrenamefolder
I:Loading page filemanagerchmod
I:Loading page filemanagerconfirm
I:Loading page filemanageraction
I:Loading page decrypt
I:Loading page decrypt_pattern
I:Loading page trydecrypt
I:Loading page terminalcommand
I:Loading page sideload
I:Loading page fixcontexts
I:Loading page slideout
I:Loading page select_storage
I:Loading page select_language
I:Loading page decrypt_users
I:Loading page changeTwrpFolder
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
Startup Commands: 
ro.boottime.adbd=3262839855
ro.boottime.init=2880
ro.boottime.init.selinux=42
ro.boottime.init.cold_boot_wait=294
ro.boottime.logd=3240154123
ro.boottime.ueventd=2936342947
ro.boottime.recovery=3243357353
ro.boottime.keymaster-3-0=3285673711
ro.boottime.sbin_qseecomd=3263326365
ro.boottime.gatekeeper-1-0=3285201524
ro.boottime.servicemanager=3263773240
ro.boottime.set_permissive=3242896311
ro.boottime.hwservicemanager=3234879123
dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant=generic
dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features=default
dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant=generic
dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features=default
dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold=500
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-dir=/data/anr
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-filter=verify-at-runtime
debug.atrace.tags.enableflags=0
ro.art.hiddenapi.warning=1
ro.boot.selinux=permissive
ro.boot.baseband=msm
ro.boot.configfs=true
ro.boot.hardware=lilac
ro.boot.keymaster=1
ro.boot.bootdevice=1da4000.ufshc
ro.boot.bootloader=xboot
ro.boot.veritymode=enforcing
ro.boot.usbcontroller=a800000.dwc3
ro.boot.verifiedbootstate=orange
ro.omni.device=lilac
ro.omni.version.security_patch=
ro.twrp.sar=true
ro.twrp.boot=1
ro.twrp.version=3.5.2_9-0
ro.vndk.lite=true
ro.vndk.version=28
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.allow.mock.location=1
ro.build.id=PQ3B.190801.002
ro.build.date=Sun Apr 11 20:36:45 UTC 2021
ro.build.date.utc=1618173405
ro.build.host=93f70f4836da
ro.build.tags=test-keys
ro.build.type=eng
ro.build.user=jenkins
ro.build.flavor=omni_lilac-eng
ro.build.display.id=omni_lilac-eng 16.1.0 PQ3B.190801.002 1 test-keys
ro.build.product=lilac
ro.build.version.sdk=28
ro.build.version.base_os=
ro.build.version.release=16.1.0
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.incremental=1
ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0
ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
ro.build.version.security_patch=2025-12-31
ro.build.version.min_supported_target_sdk=17
ro.build.description=G8441-user 9 47.2.A.11.228 3311891731 release-keys
ro.build.characteristics=default
ro.bionic.ld.warning=1
ro.kernel.android.checkjni=1
ro.secure=0
ro.treble.enabled=false
ro.product.cpu.abi=arm64-v8a
ro.product.cpu.abilist=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=
ro.product.name=lilac
ro.product.brand=Sony
ro.product.model=G8441
ro.product.device=lilac
ro.product.manufacturer=Sony
ro.baseband=msm
ro.bootmode=unknown
ro.hardware=lilac
ro.revision=0
ro.bootimage.build.date=Sun Apr 11 20:36:45 UTC 2021
ro.bootimage.build.date.utc=1618173405
ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint=Sony/G8441/G8441:9/47.2.A.11.228/3311891731:user/release-keys
ro.bootloader=xboot
ro.debuggable=1
ro.property_service.version=2
ro.actionable_compatible_property.enabled=false
fbe.contents=ice
fbe.filenames=
init.svc.adbd=running
init.svc.logd=running
init.svc.ueventd=running
init.svc.recovery=running
init.svc.keymaster-3-0=running
init.svc.sbin_qseecomd=running
init.svc.gatekeeper-1-0=running
init.svc.servicemanager=running
init.svc.set_permissive=stopped
init.svc.hwservicemanager=running
twrp.user.0.decrypt=0
twrp.crash_counter=0
crypto.ready=1
sys.usb.ffs.ready=1
ro.build.fingerprint=Sony/G8441/G8441:9/47.2.A.11.228/3311891731:user/release-keys
hwservicemanager.ready=true
ro.persistent_properties.ready=true
ro.boot.serialno=BH9086U09E
ro.serialno=BH9086U09E
service.adb.root=1
net.bt.name=Android
sys.usb.state=adb
sys.usb.controller=a800000.dwc3
persist.sys.usb.config=adb
persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2=libart.so
sys.usb.config=adb
sys.usb.configfs=1
ro.vendor.usb.pid_suffix=1F4
vendor.sys.listeners.registered=true
vendor.usb.rmnet.func.name=rmnet_bam
vendor.usb.rndis.func.name=rndis_bam
ro.crypto.type=file
ro.crypto.state=encrypted

I:Is encrypted, do decrypt page first
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
I:Set page: 'decrypt'
I:Set page: 'main'
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
I:Set page: 'install'
I:Set page: 'main'
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
SELinux contexts loaded from /file_contexts
Full SELinux support is present.
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Pre-fix date and time: 1972-11-13--05-17-29
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Setting time offset from file /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: will attempt to use the ats files now.
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Setting time offset from file /data/vendor/time/ats_2, offset 1552783865350
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Date and time corrected: 2022-01-27--06-08-34
I:Path /cache/recovery/log.gz does not exist. Unable to copy /cache/recovery/last_log.gz
I:Attempt to load settings from settings file...
I:InfoManager file '/data/media/0/TWRP/.twrps' not found.
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/BH9086U09E'
I:Copied file /etc/recovery.fstab to /cache/recovery/recovery.fstab
I:Version number saved to '/cache/recovery/.version'
I:Unable to mount '/sdcard1'
I:Actual block device: '', current file system: 'auto'
I:Unable to mount '/usb-otg'
I:Actual block device: '', current file system: 'auto'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 1600
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
parsing languageFile
parsing languageFile done
I:Translating partition display names
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/BH9086U09E'
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
I:Set page: 'system_readonly'
```

Comment: */data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db*

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation"...when trying to backup through adb (TWRP)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228390)

Comment: @alecxs the backup worked - it was created in a sub folder called 'sdcard' in %appdata%. What is next step regarding Magisk? Should I flash over adb or is there a way to modify the prop files with adb?

Comment: logcat hangs on `waiting for device` but all other steps worked

Comment: Still not working. Is this script supposed to be saved on the phone or are these commands to run through the terminal?

Comment: I did all this and `adb devices` still does not detect in normal boot

Comment: Where is this set? There is no mention of it anywhere else on this page.

Comment: Still no luck. It makes the "device connected" sound but adb devices shows nothing.

Comment: *'adb kill-server'* will restart adb. also check windows device manager for missing [drivers](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/usb_driver_r13-windows.zip) it has to be installed for each boot mode separately

Comment: you can also backup/restore on other device with [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-root-5-0-1st-nov-2020-migrate-custom-rom-migration-tool.3862763/page-79#post-83887121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have TWRP so first create backup of whole `userdata` partition with `adb pull`
(Note: backup is encrypted and useless outside of source phone)

```
adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
```

If your TWRP support encryption you can just *"unlock"* ([decrypt](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html)) phone from command line and backup plain `userdata` partition instead

```
adb shell twrp decrypt '1234'
adb pull /dev/block/dm-0
```

It will take up to 1 hour and requires several GB disk space on your NTFS or ext4 formatted hard disk. This step is optional and backup can deleted from PC afterwards, it is not required.

Instead full disk image consider using twrp adb backup. This backup does not include your emulated Internal Storage. Pull pictures and music from `/sdcard` yourself

```
adb backup --twrp --compress data
adb pull -a /sdcard
```

---

If your `/data` partition is accessable you can enable [usb-debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116) via Magisk startup script in [/data/adb/service.d](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#boot-scripts)
([settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#summary) vary on android version)

```
cd %userprofile%
adb push .android\adbkey.pub /sdcard
adb shell
echo '#!/system/bin/sh
      sleep 15
      settings put global development_settings_enabled 1
      settings put global usb_mass_storage_enabled 1
      settings put global adb_enabled 1
     ' > /data/adb/service.d/adbguard
chmod 0755 /data/adb/service.d/adbguard
```

and [authorize](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171934) your computer RSA key `adbkey.pub` "offline" (this [flashable.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-magiskhide-props-config-safetynet-prop-edits-and-more-v6-1-2.3789228/page-301#post-86327477) can do it, too)

```
cat /sdcard/adbkey.pub >> /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
chmod 0640 /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
chown 1000.2000 /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
chcon u:object_r:adb_keys_file:s0 /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
```

---

Otherwise modify `/system_root/prop.default`, `/system_root/system/build.prop` or whatever until you got `scrcpy` to work (you can try that [update.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4111923) for this)

---

Next, boot into android and check `adb devices` you should be able to [control your phone screen from PC](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) with `scrcpy` now. please note `scrcpy` comes with it's own `adb.exe` - please delete it to avoid losing `adbkey.pub` (scrcpy will use adb.exe from [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) instead after you added `platform-tools` directory to `%PATH%`)

[image]

---

Finally, install [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31155) and backup your SMS. you can restore to different phone by copying the files into proper directory and restore it -> *"In original storage"*

[image]

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\MyPhoneExplorer\<device>[<IMEI>]\SMS.dat
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\MyPhoneExplorer\<device>[<IMEI>]\SMSArchive.dat
```